# Scipy Optimization Algorithms: Early stopping

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, differential-evolution, early-stopping

I want to know how to trigger early stopping for scipy optimization algorithms like differential evolution, dual annealing, and basin hopping.

I know you can call a callback function that returns True or False, but, I wanted to know how to trigger the whole algorithm to stop when the fitness function converge to the same value for several itertaions. For instance, if the maxiter is set to 250, but the fitness function converged at 100 iterations, how do i trigger it to stop when it is no longer making any improvements?

Comment: `maxiter` is when to stop if it *doesn't* converge (i.e., fails). If you get the same number more than once, it will terminate. That's the whole point.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `maxiter` parameter, there is a tolerance that determines convergence. All the algorithms stop once they reach the convergence criterion.

Take [`differential_evolution`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html) as an example. It has two tolerance parameters (most have only the first one):

> **tol : *float, optional***
>
> Relative tolerance for convergence, the solving stops when `np.std(pop) <= atol + tol * np.abs(np.mean(population_energies))`, where and *atol* and *tol* are the absolute and relative tolerance respectively.
>
> ...
>
> **atol : *float, optional***
>
> Absolute tolerance for convergence, the solving stops when `np.std(pop) <= atol + tol * np.abs(np.mean(population_energies))`, where and *atol* and *tol* are the absolute and relative tolerance respectively.